# Не отправляются данные формы

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap4

Не отправляются данные с формы, я так понял это из-за того что я в форме блоки сделал, можно как-то отправлять с вложенных блоков или нужно создавать без них,?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyprod">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="buyprod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background:black;">
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold" style="color:white;text-transform:uppercase;">Заказ товара</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="font-size:30px;font-weight:800;color:white;">X
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body mx-3" style="padding-bottom:0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
            <p class="prodname text-center" style="color:white;"></p>
            <p class="text-center" style="color:white;">Количество, цвет и все детали уточним по телефону. Оставьте свой номер для оформления заказа.</p>
            <form action="success.php" method="post">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" required style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-bottom:0;height:50px;border-radius:8px;border-color:white;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;padding-left:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <img src="img/arrform1.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:80px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-right" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <img src="img/arrform2.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:80px;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваше имя" required style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-bottom:0;height:50px;border-radius:8px;border-color:white;margin-bottom:5px;padding-left:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <div class="row" style="background:white;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-right" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <button class="btn text-center" type="button" name="button" style="border-width:2px;border-color:black;font-weight:800;background:white;">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <img src="img/arrright.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:60px;position:relative;top:30px;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-left" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <img src="img/cart.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:60px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: на input'ах стоит required, при нажатии не выдает предупреждение, и не переходит по адресу в action

Comment: ну для начала хотя бы у кнопки замените на type="submit"

Comment: @Kjuri извините за мою глупость, заменил на submit всё заработало, напишите ответ я поставлю галочку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у кнопки замените на type="submit